# NSPredicate getting first digit

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

I'm trying to fetch data from `CoreData` using `NSPredicate`. The problem is, I only need to compare the first digit of the value of the entity:

```
class Foo: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var value: NSNumber // random number 1xx - 7xx

}
```

My current predicate is comparing the complete value:

```
NSPredicate(format: "value == %d", 5)
```

I've also tried using `.filter` instead but after testing, it shows it's over twice as slow in my case.

**Question:**
How should I change my predicate so it can compare the first digit of `value`?

Comment: Do all numbers have 3 digits? Then `NSPredicate(format: "value >= %d AND value <= %d", 500, 599)`  would work.

Comment: @MartinR Yes they all have 3 digits, but what I haven't explained properly is that `5` is a dynamic number. It could be between `0` and `10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a Core Data predicate which checks for the first digit
of a number. For *strings* you could use `BEGINSWITH`.

But if (as in your case) all numbers have 3 digits then you can create a predicate for numbers in a given *range* instead:

```
let digit = 5 // some number in the range 0...9
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "value >= %ld AND value <= %ld", digit * 100, digit * 100 + 99)
```

(Note that the correct format for `Int` arguments is `%ld`.)

Comment: Thanks, I was too fixated on getting the first digit of `value` instead of finding another way to solve it.